# Switch executes first case instead of default when using string and enum map

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, enums, stl

I want to use strings that are mapped to an enum member. The enum values will later be used in a switch to determine what functions will be executed. I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#define MSG_BUFSIZE 100

enum CMDVAL
{
    CMD_USEREXIT,
    CMD_LOGIN
};

std::map<std::string, CMDVAL> map_cmdval;

void initCmdmap()
{
    map_cmdval["exit"] = CMD_USEREXIT;
    map_cmdval["login"] = CMD_LOGIN;
}

bool RUNNING = true;

int main()
{
    initCmdmap();
    char buffer[MSG_BUFSIZE];

    while(RUNNING)
    {
        memset(buffer, '\0', MSG_BUFSIZE);
        std::cin.getline(buffer, MSG_BUFSIZE);

        switch (map_cmdval[buffer])
        {
            case CMD_USEREXIT:
                RUNNING = false;
                printf("Exiting...\n");
                break;
            case CMD_LOGIN:
                printf("Logging in...\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid command\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles, however if I try to input a different word than the ones already defined in the map, the CMD_USEREXIT case will be executed instead of the default case. What am I missing? And most importantly why is this happening?

Comment: What you're missing is knowing what happens when you use the `[]` operator with a key that does not exist in the map. What value do you believe the `[]` operator will return, in this case? It has to return something, it has no choice in that matter. Your C++ book has the answer to this weighty question, and your C++ book will also tell you how enum values are generated. By putting two and two together, you will then understand exactly what's happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, *performing an insertion if such key does not already exist*.

This means, when you read a value `foo` from stdin, a new element `map_cmdval["foo"]` will be inserted with a default value of 0.

The definition of [`enum CMDVAL`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) is equivalent to

```
enum CMDVAL
{
    CMD_USEREXIT = 0,
    CMD_LOGIN = 1
};
```

`map_cmdval["foo"]` gives you a value of 0, which is the same as `CMD_USEREXIT`.